# How to round values of a Float List in Animation Nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

*Math* node only has Floor and Ceiling modes, while *Float to Integer* or *Round* nodes don't work with *Float List* (sockets doesn't connect in v2.1 (for 2.79b). Am I missing something here?

Making a Loop just to accomplish rounding seems to be overcomlicated for this task.

Comment: @MartinZ Animation nodes probably, see tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding 0.5 before flooring gives you rounding. Alternatively, subtracting 0.5 before ceiling gives you rounding.